# What is the option to KML for Snap to Road Option (Features)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, google-earth

> I am using Gmap to show direction between Start and End Points with
>   Waypoints included.

Points are properly shown when using the Gmap DirectionService but not working while generating the KML.
My Original output: [image]

I want same for KML But,
While generating the KML file for google Earth and Gmap it will marker [image]

What is the option i have to set in my KML file to show each point up to that route is available.

Can anyone help out?

**My Working Code for Gmap: ( It is good for me ) I want options for KML to give same output.**

[My Code is here for Gmap](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwinparmar/NStmN/)

My Original Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:1024px;height:500px;">Map Loading...</div>
<script>
    var start   = "46.9502622421856, 7.93212890625";
    var end     = "46.97978388900174, 7.944059371948242";
    var waypts = [];
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var checkboxArray;
    var mywaypoints = "46.94868026561828,7.962899208068848;46.96315067896921,7.982726097106934";

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: chicago
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calcRoute();
    }

    function calcRoute() {
        checkboxArray = mywaypoints.split(/;/);
        checkboxArray.forEach(function(point) {
            waypts.push({
                location: point,
                stopover: true,
            });
        });

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: false,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
    initialize();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[**My KML File:**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwinparmar/TX3Kh/)

Comment: Hi, ashwin. May I kno how you got the KML output, I am struggling in that. Please help me in this.